# Can I Suppress a specific package used by another package?

Tags: mla-style

I'm using the MLA package to write my essays, however the package is a little dated so it uses the thumbpdf package. This doesn't do any harm to my essay, but it does produce annoying warning messages. Is there anyway to use the MLA package, but not thumbpdf?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\PreventPackageFromLoading{thumbpdf}` from package `scrlfile` before `\usepackage{mla}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{scrlfile}
\PreventPackageFromLoading{thumbpdf}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{mla}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, wish the mla package got updated. Thanks!